# Angular how to check from which component is a div

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, dom

I'm interested in how to check in console which component was rendered. I mean, let's assume that in console -> Elements you can see a lot of divs, for example. How can you check from which component are this divs coming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply inspect the `HTML`in Chromes' Dev Tools. Simply by right-clicking and selecting `inspect`. In the `Elements` section where all of the page's `HTML` is shown you can see different `<div>` etc. If you observe it closely there are also tags of components that are used by angular to display those `<div>`.

For example, in the simple stackblitz Angular project. Simple inspection of the HTML will show us this

[image: Example Image for Inspection]

Here you can see that `<h1>` is inside the `hello-component` of Angular which is shown by `<hello .... >` tag. Which is inside another component `my-app-component` called `<my-app...>`. By this logic, you can easily see which `HTML` is inside which Angular Component

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<div><div></div></div>'
})
export class MyComponent {
...
}
```

If you add the component above in your app, you should be able to see `<my-component>...</my-component>` in your DevTools > Elements panel.

You can also use the [Angular DevTools extension](https://angular.io/guide/devtools) to explore the HTML of your components.